# Composer: Laravel/passport requires illuminate/auth ~5.3.* but locked to v5.2.45

Tags: composer-php, lumen, laravel-passport

I am trying to add [lumen-passport](https://packagist.org/packages/dusterio/lumen-passport) to my Lumen project via the following command `composer require dusterio/lumen-passport` but is being halted due to my `illuminate/auth` version.

```
Problem 1
- Installation request for dusterio/lumen-passport ^0.1.9 -> satisfiable by dusterio/lumen-passport[0.1.9].
- Conclusion: remove illuminate/auth v5.2.45
- Conclusion: don't install illuminate/auth v5.2.45
- dusterio/lumen-passport 0.1.9 requires laravel/passport >=0.2.2 -> satisfiable by laravel/passport[v0.2.2, v0.2.3, v0.2.4, v1.0.0, v1.0.1, v1.0.10, v1.0.11, v1.0.12, v1.0.13, v1.0.14, v1.0.15, v1.0.16, v1.0.17, v1.0.2, v1.0.3, v1.0.4, v1.0.5, v1.0.6, v1.0.7, v1.0.8, v1.0.9, v2.0.0, v2.0.1, v2.0.2, v2.0.3, v2.0.4].
- laravel/passport v0.2.2 requires illuminate/auth ~5.3 -> satisfiable by illuminate/auth[v5.3.0, v5.3.16, v5.3.23, v5.3.4, v5.4.0, v5.4.9].
- laravel/passport v0.2.3 requires illuminate/auth ~5.3 -> satisfiable by illuminate/auth[v5.3.0, v5.3.16, v5.3.23, v5.3.4, v5.4.0, v5.4.9].
- laravel/passport v0.2.4 requires illuminate/auth ~5.3 -> satisfiable by illuminate/auth[v5.3.0, v5.3.16, v5.3.23, v5.3.4, v5.4.0, v5.4.9].
- laravel/passport v1.0.0 requires illuminate/auth ~5.3 -> satisfiable by illuminate/auth[v5.3.0, v5.3.16, v5.3.23, v5.3.4, v5.4.0, v5.4.9].
- laravel/passport v1.0.1 requires illuminate/auth ~5.3 -> satisfiable by illuminate/auth[v5.3.0, v5.3.16, v5.3.23, v5.3.4, v5.4.0, v5.4.9].
- laravel/passport v1.0.10 requires illuminate/auth ~5.3 -> satisfiable by illuminate/auth[v5.3.0, v5.3.16, v5.3.23, v5.3.4, v5.4.0, v5.4.9].
- laravel/passport v1.0.11 requires illuminate/auth ~5.3 -> satisfiable by illuminate/auth[v5.3.0, v5.3.16, v5.3.23, v5.3.4, v5.4.0, v5.4.9].
- laravel/passport v1.0.12 requires illuminate/auth ~5.3 -> satisfiable by illuminate/auth[v5.3.0, v5.3.16, v5.3.23, v5.3.4, v5.4.0, v5.4.9].
- laravel/passport v1.0.13 requires illuminate/auth ~5.3 -> satisfiable by illuminate/auth[v5.3.0, v5.3.16, v5.3.23, v5.3.4, v5.4.0, v5.4.9].
- laravel/passport v1.0.14 requires illuminate/auth ~5.3 -> satisfiable by illuminate/auth[v5.3.0, v5.3.16, v5.3.23, v5.3.4, v5.4.0, v5.4.9].
- laravel/passport v1.0.15 requires illuminate/auth ~5.3 -> satisfiable by illuminate/auth[v5.3.0, v5.3.16, v5.3.23, v5.3.4, v5.4.0, v5.4.9].
- laravel/passport v1.0.16 requires illuminate/auth ~5.3 -> satisfiable by illuminate/auth[v5.3.0, v5.3.16, v5.3.23, v5.3.4, v5.4.0, v5.4.9].
- laravel/passport v1.0.17 requires illuminate/auth ~5.3 -> satisfiable by illuminate/auth[v5.3.0, v5.3.16, v5.3.23, v5.3.4, v5.4.0, v5.4.9].
- laravel/passport v1.0.2 requires illuminate/auth ~5.3 -> satisfiable by illuminate/auth[v5.3.0, v5.3.16, v5.3.23, v5.3.4, v5.4.0, v5.4.9].
- laravel/passport v1.0.3 requires illuminate/auth ~5.3 -> satisfiable by illuminate/auth[v5.3.0, v5.3.16, v5.3.23, v5.3.4, v5.4.0, v5.4.9].
- laravel/passport v1.0.4 requires illuminate/auth ~5.3 -> satisfiable by illuminate/auth[v5.3.0, v5.3.16, v5.3.23, v5.3.4, v5.4.0, v5.4.9].
- laravel/passport v1.0.5 requires illuminate/auth ~5.3 -> satisfiable by illuminate/auth[v5.3.0, v5.3.16, v5.3.23, v5.3.4, v5.4.0, v5.4.9].
- laravel/passport v1.0.6 requires illuminate/auth ~5.3 -> satisfiable by illuminate/auth[v5.3.0, v5.3.16, v5.3.23, v5.3.4, v5.4.0, v5.4.9].
- laravel/passport v1.0.7 requires illuminate/auth ~5.3 -> satisfiable by illuminate/auth[v5.3.0, v5.3.16, v5.3.23, v5.3.4, v5.4.0, v5.4.9].
- laravel/passport v1.0.8 requires illuminate/auth ~5.3 -> satisfiable by illuminate/auth[v5.3.0, v5.3.16, v5.3.23, v5.3.4, v5.4.0, v5.4.9].
- laravel/passport v1.0.9 requires illuminate/auth ~5.3 -> satisfiable by illuminate/auth[v5.3.0, v5.3.16, v5.3.23, v5.3.4, v5.4.0, v5.4.9].
- laravel/passport v2.0.0 requires illuminate/auth ~5.4 -> satisfiable by illuminate/auth[v5.4.0, v5.4.9].
- laravel/passport v2.0.1 requires illuminate/auth ~5.4 -> satisfiable by illuminate/auth[v5.4.0, v5.4.9].
- laravel/passport v2.0.2 requires illuminate/auth ~5.4 -> satisfiable by illuminate/auth[v5.4.0, v5.4.9].
- laravel/passport v2.0.3 requires illuminate/auth ~5.4 -> satisfiable by illuminate/auth[v5.4.0, v5.4.9].
- laravel/passport v2.0.4 requires illuminate/auth ~5.4 -> satisfiable by illuminate/auth[v5.4.0, v5.4.9].
- Can only install one of: illuminate/auth[v5.3.0, v5.2.45].
- Can only install one of: illuminate/auth[v5.3.16, v5.2.45].
- Can only install one of: illuminate/auth[v5.3.23, v5.2.45].
- Can only install one of: illuminate/auth[v5.3.4, v5.2.45].
- Can only install one of: illuminate/auth[v5.4.0, v5.2.45].
- Can only install one of: illuminate/auth[v5.4.9, v5.2.45].
- Installation request for illuminate/auth (locked at v5.2.45) -> satisfiable by illuminate/auth[v5.2.45].
```

And here is what is shown when I execute `composer show`

```
doctrine/inflector                v1.1.0  Common String Manipulations with regard to casing and singular/plural ru...
doctrine/instantiator             1.0.5   A small, lightweight utility to instantiate objects in PHP without invok...
fzaninotto/faker                  v1.6.0  Faker is a PHP library that generates fake data for you.
illuminate/auth                   v5.2.45 The Illuminate Auth package.
illuminate/broadcasting           v5.2.45 The Illuminate Broadcasting package.
illuminate/bus                    v5.2.45 The Illuminate Bus package.
illuminate/cache                  v5.2.45 The Illuminate Cache package.
illuminate/config                 v5.2.45 The Illuminate Config package.
illuminate/console                v5.2.45 The Illuminate Console package.
illuminate/container              v5.2.45 The Illuminate Container package.
illuminate/contracts              v5.2.45 The Illuminate Contracts package.
illuminate/database               v5.2.45 The Illuminate Database package.
illuminate/encryption             v5.2.45 The Illuminate Encryption package.
illuminate/events                 v5.2.45 The Illuminate Events package.
illuminate/filesystem             v5.2.45 The Illuminate Filesystem package.
illuminate/hashing                v5.2.45 The Illuminate Hashing package.
illuminate/http                   v5.2.45 The Illuminate Http package.
illuminate/pagination             v5.2.45 The Illuminate Pagination package.
illuminate/pipeline               v5.2.45 The Illuminate Pipeline package.
illuminate/queue                  v5.2.45 The Illuminate Queue package.
illuminate/session                v5.2.45 The Illuminate Session package.
illuminate/support                v5.2.45 The Illuminate Support package.
illuminate/translation            v5.2.45 The Illuminate Translation package.
illuminate/validation             v5.2.45 The Illuminate Validation package.
illuminate/view                   v5.2.45 The Illuminate View package.
laravel/lumen-framework           v5.2.9  The Laravel Lumen Framework.
monolog/monolog                   1.22.0  Sends your logs to files, sockets, inboxes, databases and various web se...
mtdowling/cron-expression         v1.2.0  CRON for PHP: Calculate the next or previous run date and determine if a...
nesbot/carbon                     1.22.1  A simple API extension for DateTime.
nikic/fast-route                  v0.7.0  Fast request router for PHP
paragonie/random_compat           v1.4.1  PHP 5.x polyfill for random_bytes() and random_int() from PHP 7
phpdocumentor/reflection-common   1.0     Common reflection classes used by             phpdocumentor to reflect the code stru...
phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock 3.1.1   With this component, a library can provide support for annotations via D...
phpdocumentor/type-resolver       0.2.1
phpspec/prophecy                  v1.6.2  Highly opinionated mocking framework for PHP 5.3+
phpunit/php-code-coverage         2.2.4   Library that provides collection,     processing, and rendering functionalit...
phpunit/php-file-iterator         1.4.2   FilterIterator implementation that filters files based on a list of suff...
phpunit/php-text-template         1.2.1   Simple template engine.
phpunit/php-timer                 1.0.8   Utility class for timing
phpunit/php-token-stream          1.4.9   Wrapper around PHP's tokenizer extension.
phpunit/phpunit                   4.8.35  The PHP Unit Testing framework.
phpunit/phpunit-mock-objects      2.3.8   Mock Object library for PHPUnit
psr/log                           1.0.2   Common interface for logging libraries
sebastian/comparator              1.2.4   Provides the functionality to compare PHP values for equality
sebastian/diff                    1.4.1   Diff implementation
sebastian/environment             1.3.8   Provides functionality to handle HHVM/PHP environments
sebastian/exporter                1.2.2   Provides the functionality to export PHP variables for visualization
sebastian/global-state            1.1.1   Snapshotting of global state
sebastian/recursion-context       1.0.2   Provides functionality to recursively process PHP variables
sebastian/version                 1.0.6   Library that helps with managing the version number of Git-hosted PHP pr...
symfony/console                   v3.0.9  Symfony Console Component
symfony/debug                     v3.0.9  Symfony Debug Component
symfony/event-dispatcher          v3.2.4  Symfony EventDispatcher Component
symfony/finder                    v3.0.9  Symfony Finder Component
symfony/http-foundation           v3.0.9  Symfony HttpFoundation Component
symfony/http-kernel               v3.0.9  Symfony HttpKernel Component
symfony/polyfill-mbstring         v1.3.0  Symfony polyfill for the Mbstring extension
symfony/polyfill-php56            v1.3.0  Symfony polyfill backporting some PHP 5.6+ features to lower PHP versions
symfony/polyfill-util             v1.3.0  Symfony utilities for portability of PHP codes
symfony/process                   v3.0.9  Symfony Process Component
symfony/translation               v3.0.9  Symfony Translation Component
symfony/yaml                      v3.2.4  Symfony Yaml Component
vlucas/phpdotenv                  v2.4.0  Loads environment variables from `.env` to `getenv()`, `$_ENV` and `$_SE...
webmozart/assert                  1.2.0   Assertions to validate method input/output with nice error messages.
```

And finally the `composer.json`

```
{
    "name": "laravel/lumen",
    "description": "The Laravel Lumen Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel", "lumen"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.5.9",
        "laravel/lumen-framework": "5.2.*",
        "vlucas/phpdotenv": "~2.2"
    },
        "require-dev": {
        "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~4.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "classmap": [
            "tests/",
            "database/"
        ]
    }
}
```

I have the most recent version of Lumen installed `v5.4.4`. It seems like a `laravel/passport` dependency problem and not so much `lumen-passport` however the instructions on [packagist](https://packagist.org/packages/dusterio/lumen-passport) mention that `lumen-passport` will be grabbed along the way.

It just seems like my version of `illuminate/auth` needs to be updated however the composer.lock file has it limited to v5.2.45 and for that reason I am hesitant to make any changes to the file and not overly sure how to proceed with resolving this dependency issue so I can install [lumen-passport](https://packagist.org/packages/dusterio/lumen-passport). Appreciate any help with this.

Comment: can you add your `composer.json` too?

Comment: Ah of course - Added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that your dependencies are up to date? Check the versions you have installed with `composer show`.

`lumen-passport 0.1.9` requires `laravel/passport >=0.2.2` and this requires at least `illuminate/auth ~5.3` or higher. But your `illuminate/auth` is locked to `5.2.45`. I suggest to update at least `laravel/passport` or do a `composer update`. Make sure you have a backup before update.

Comment: Thanks for your post. I have edited my main post to show what `composer show` produces. I also ran `composer update` and there was no updates to get. I can't install `laravel/passport` via `lumen-passport` to update because from what I understand of the composer logs is that the `illuminate/auth` requirement is not met and for that reason it terminates. So I am a bit stuck as to where to go from here.

Comment: you are **not** on the latest version of Lumen! `"laravel/lumen-framework": "5.2.*",` latest stable version of Lumen is `5.3` make sure to [upgrade](https://lumen.laravel.com/docs/5.4/upgrade) at least to to most stable Lumen version `5.3` or  `5.4` !

Comment: Sigh, no idea how I missed that. I thought this file system for lumen came from GitHub which page says it's `5.4.4` is stable but it was a previous file system and my current installation came from using `composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/lumen`. Thank you for your help.